# Redux вытащить данные из fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Решил попробовать redux, после useContext. Почитал про диспатч и разные инструменты, но не понял. Можно ли вытащить просто данные из fetch по примеру контекста и хука?

```
import {createStore} from "redux";


let storedAds;

    fetch(`https://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[depth]=0`, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            const adsNumber = result.data.map(item => +item.objectsCountByType);
            const reducer = adsNumber.reduce(function (sum, current){
                return sum + current
            }, 0)
            storedAds = reducer
            return  storedAds
        })




const store = createStore(() => ({
    add: storedAds
})
)

export default store;
```

Comment: Не понятно, чего вы хотите достичь. В вашем `fetch` методом `dispatch` отправляете полученные данных в хранилище redux, а в нужном компоненте, используя `useSelector` получаете эти данные

Comment: @Александр, возможно в этой теме есть подходящие для тебя варианты.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813984/how-to-fetch-data-through-api-in-redux